# async for loop with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate a browser using puppeteer.js and I am clicking a div in a long list of divs that are in a modal and scroll. I loop through which divs I want to click on and click on them in order. It seems like if I give the browser enough time it'll scroll to the right position and then click the div.

This example works:

```
users_names[14].click().catch(function(error){console.log("some error ", "position", error)});
await delay(2000);
users_names[45].click().catch(function(error){console.log("some error ", "position", error)});
await delay(2000);
users_names[54].click().catch(function(error){console.log("some error ", "position", error)});
await delay(2000);
users_names[0].click().catch(function(error){console.log("some error ", "position", error)});
await delay(2000);
users_names[29].click().catch(function(error){console.log("some error ", "position", error)});
```

But obviously if I want to click on different elements I can't have them hard coded. I tried doing this, but it goes through too quickly to scroll and click on the elements.

```
_.forEach(namesToSend, function(n) {
    var position = memberOrder.indexOf(n)
    console.log('position: ', position)
    if(position != -1)
    users_names[position].click().catch(function(error){console.log("some error ", position, error)});
});
```

How can I make this loop slow down so it waits for the click event before moving on?

Comment: Did answer I provided fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe click method returns a promise so inside `ForEach` it wouldn't work. you need to use `for..of` loop like this

```
for (const name of namesToSend) {
  try {
    var position = memberOrder.indexOf(name);
    if (position != -1) await users_names[position].click();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("some error ", position, error);
  }
}
```